# Cannot be resolved to a type errors when following Android NFC Tutorial / Example

Tags: java, android, eclipse, nfc

I'm attempting to use the following example source code to add NFC functionality to my app:

http://gitorious.org/0xdroid/development/blobs/150dd1693ff06a7683076eebe669277631dedf06/samples/NFCDemo/src/com/example/android/nfc/TagViewer.java

However when I do so I'm getting several "cannot be resolved to a type" errors.

...anyone have any suggestions?

P.S.

I have a feeling it stems from the line: `import com.nfc.linked.record.ParsedNdefRecord;`

but I'm not sure how to fix the issue.

ERRORS:

```
ParsedNdefRecord cannot be resolved to a type       line 97 Java Problem
title_scanned_tag cannot be resolved or is not a field      line 77 Java Problem
ParsedNdefRecord cannot be resolved to a type       line 100    Java Problem
NdefMessageParser cannot be resolved        line 97 Java Problem
The import com.nfc.linked.record cannot be resolved     line 30 Java Problem
title cannot be resolved or is not a field      line 51 Java Problem
list cannot be resolved or is not a field       line 50 Java Problem
```

SOURCE:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.nfc.NdefMessage;
import android.nfc.NdefRecord;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.nfc.linked.record.ParsedNdefRecord;
import java.util.List;


public class AppActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener  {

    static final String TAG = "ViewTag";
    static final int ACTIVITY_TIMEOUT_MS = 1 * 1000;
    private TextView mTitle;
    private LinearLayout mTagContent;   
        private Button b;






        @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mTagContent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.list);
    mTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    resolveIntent(getIntent());
    b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);


}

        void resolveIntent(Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
                if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
                    Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
                                NdefMessage[] msgs;
                                if (rawMsgs != null) {
                                    msgs = new NdefMessage[rawMsgs.length];
                                    for (int i = 0; i < rawMsgs.length; i++) {
                                        msgs[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[i];
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    // Unknown tag type
                                    byte[] empty = new byte[] {};
                                    NdefRecord record = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_UNKNOWN, empty, empty, empty);
                                    NdefMessage msg = new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] {record});
                                    msgs = new NdefMessage[] {msg};
                                }

                                setTitle(R.string.title_scanned_tag);
                                            buildTagViews(msgs);
                                        } else {
                                            Log.e(TAG, "Unknown intent " + intent);
                                            finish();
                                            return;
                                        }
                                    }

        void buildTagViews(NdefMessage[] msgs) {
                    if (msgs == null || msgs.length == 0) {
                        return;
                    }
                    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
                    LinearLayout content = mTagContent;
                    // Clear out any old views in the content area, for example if you scan
                    // two tags in a row.
                    content.removeAllViews();
                    // Parse the first message in the list
                    // Build views for all of the sub records
                    List<ParsedNdefRecord> records = NdefMessageParser.parse(msgs[0]);
                    final int size = records.size();
                    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                        ParsedNdefRecord record = records.get(i);
                        content.addView(record.getView(this, inflater, content, i));
                        inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, content, true);
                    }
                }
        @Override
            public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
                setIntent(intent);
                resolveIntent(intent);
            }
            @Override
            public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
                mTitle.setText(title);
            }




@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
    Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
    .setTicker("Link Access Granted!")
    .setContentTitle("Linking Manager")
    .setContentText("Link Access Granted!")
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_notify_template3)
    .setContentIntent(pIntent).getNotification();
    noti.flags=Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
    Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(startMain);

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its not finding anything in your library for nfc records.  If you're using eclipse, make sure that the library is included in your project, and that in the far right tab of the java build screen the library is checked and above the src folder for your project.  If you're using something else, check the equivalent classpath settings.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "check to make sure the library is included in my project"

Comment: com.nfc.linked.record is a library I assume.  If that's your own project, then eclipse is even more screwed up.  Outside libraries have to be added to your project, either as librarys or jars in the 3rd tab of the Java Build Path property for the project.

Comment: I'm using the source code from the URL posted above. Any idea where I might find it? I've googled it but I'm not finding much.

Comment: YOu can find the missing code at http://code.google.com/p/ketai/source/browse/NFCDemo/src/com/example/android/nfc/?r=194